# I have problems connecting django with outlook

Tags: django

## settings.py

```
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

# Configuración del backend de correo electrónico
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
# Host y puerto del servidor de correo electrónico
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com' #ejemplo: smtp.gmail.com, smtp.office365.com
EMAIL_PORT = 587
# Configuración de TLS (Transport Layer Security)
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True #False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False #True
# Credenciales de autenticación del servidor de correo electrónico
OUTLOOK_EMAIL = config('OUTLOOK_EMAIL')
OUTLOOK_PASSWORD = config('OUTLOOK_PASSWORD')
# Dirección de correo electrónico utilizada para enviar correos desde el sistema
#DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'example@example.cl'
FROM_EMAIL = config('OUTLOOK_EMAIL')
```

## `views.py`

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        message = request.POST.get('message')

        # Configura los datos de Outlook
        remitente = email
        destinatario = os.getenv("OUTLOOK_EMAIL")
        clave_outlook = os.getenv("OUTLOOK_PASSWORD")

        # Configura el mensaje de correo electrónico
        email_message = f"Nombre: {name}\nCorreo: {email}\nTeléfono: {phone}\nMensaje: {message}"

        # Crea el objeto del mensaje
        email = EmailMessage()
        email["From"] = remitente
        email["To"] = destinatario
        email["Subject"] = "Nuevo mensaje de contacto desde el sitio web"
        email.set_content(email_message)

        try:
            # Configura el servidor SMTP de Outlook
            smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp-mail.outlook.com", port=587)
            smtp.starttls()
            # Imprime en la consola las credenciales y el mensaje
            print(f'Destinatario: {destinatario}, Mensaje: {email_message}')
            smtp.login(destinatario, clave_outlook) 

            # Envía el mensaje
            smtp.sendmail(remitente, destinatario, email.as_string())
            smtp.quit()

            # Muestra un mensaje de éxito en la respuesta HTTP
            messages.success(request, '¡El mensaje fue enviado correctamente!')

        except Exception as e:
            # Muestra un mensaje de error en la respuesta HTTP
            messages.error(request, f'Ocurrió un error al enviar el mensaje: {str(e)}')
            print(f'Error al enviar el mensaje: {str(e)}')

    # Renderiza la plantilla del formulario si el método no es POST
    return render(request, 'Contacto/contact.html' )
```

## `.env`

```
OUTLOOK_EMAIL=example@example.cl
OUTLOOK_PASSWORD="my password"
```

## `contact.html`

```
{% extends 'Inicio/layout.html' %}
{% block body %}
<!-- Page content-->
<section class="py-5">
    <div class="container px-5">
        <!-- Contact form-->
        <div class="bg-light rounded-3 py-5 px-4 px-md-5 mb-5">
            <div class="text-center mb-5">
                <div class="feature bg-primary bg-gradient text-white rounded-3 mb-3"><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i></div>
                <h1 class="fw-bolder">Contactanos</h1>
                <p class="lead fw-normal text-muted mb-0">Nos comunicaremos contigo lo antes posible!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row gx-5 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-6">

                    <form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'contact' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                
                        <!-- Name input -->
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name..." required>
                            <label for="name">Nombre y Apellido</label>
                        </div>
                
                        <!-- Email address input -->
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                        </div>
                
                        <!-- Phone number input -->
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input class="form-control" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" required>
                            <label for="phone">Telefono</label>
                        </div>
                
                        <!-- Message input -->
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here..." style="height: 10rem" required></textarea>
                            <label for="message">Mensaje</label>
                        </div>
                
                        <!-- Submit Button -->
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                    </form>
                    <!-- Mensajes de éxito o error -->
                    {% if messages %}
                        <ul class="messages">
                            {% for message in messages %}
                                <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                    <!-- Contact cards-->
                    <div class="row gx-5 row-cols-2 row-cols-lg-4 py-5">
                        <div class="col">
                            <a href="https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=es-419&ictx=2&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieqqL53rKDAxXbObkGHSijCAoQPQgJ" target="_blank" class="text-decoration-none">
                                <div class="feature bg-primary bg-gradient text-white rounded-3 mb-3"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"></i></div>
                                <div class="h5 mb-2">Whatsapp</div>
                                <p class="text-muted mb-0">Chatea con nosotros mediante nuestro Whatsapp.</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/dessin-electronica-limitada/" target="_blank" class="text-decoration-none">
                                <div class="feature bg-primary bg-gradient text-white rounded-3 mb-3"><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></div>
                                <div class="h5">LinkedIn</div>
                                <p class="text-muted mb-0">Conéctate con nosotros en LinkedIn.</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=61552806265621" target="_blank" class="text-decoration-none">
                                <div class="feature bg-primary bg-gradient text-white rounded-3 mb-3"><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i></div>
                                <div class="h5">Facebook</div>
                                <p class="text-muted mb-0">Síguenos en Facebook para obtener actualizaciones.</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dessin_soluciones?utm_source=ig_web_button_share_sheet&igsh=OGQ5ZDc2ODk2ZA==" target="_blank" class="text-decoration-none">
                                <div class="feature bg-primary bg-gradient text-white rounded-3 mb-3"><i class="bi bi-instagram"></i></div>
                                <div class="h5">Instagram</div>
                                <p class="text-muted mb-0">Síguenos en Instagram para ver nuestras fotos.</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</section>
        </main>
{% endblock %}
```

## `forms.py`

```
from django import forms

class ContactoForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Full name', max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address')
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Phone number', max_length=20)
    message = forms.CharField(label='Message', widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean_phone(self):
        phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']

        return phone
```

`Hello, I have been working on an app in Django in which I must implement a contact form which the client can complete with their data and then I should receive the email with the information that the client entered to the Outlook business email, this is what I had done it before but with Gmail and Outlook it seems they are not the same. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

`the console shows me this:`

```
Destinatario: example@example.cl, Mensaje: Nombre: antony maza Correo: antonymaza@gmail.com Teléfono: 987389823 Mensaje: mensaje de prueba

Error sending message: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [RO2P152CA0088.LAMP152.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-01-02T13:09:20.408Z 08DC0B774749E7B1]') [02/Jan/2024 10:09:20] "POST /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10137 Destinatario: example@example.cl, Mensaje: Nombre: antony maza Correo: antonymaza15@gmail.com Teléfono: 946808240 Mensaje: mensaje de prueba Error sending message: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [SCYPR80CA0001.lamprd80.prod.outlook.com 2024-01-02T14:33:15.161Z 08DC0AC08CEE5E2E]') [02/Jan/2024 11:33:15] "POST /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10138
```

`and under the form in my html it shows me this:`

```
An error occurred while sending the message: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [SCYPR80CA0001.lamprd80.prod.outlook.com 2024-01-02T14:33:15.161Z 08DC0AC08CEE5E2E]')`
```